# Refactor a condition

Tags: c++, refactoring, c++14

There is a condition for a,b,c,d,e,f,g of type unsigned int given as follows:

```
if ((a > 0) and (b < a) and (c >= d))
{
    return ((e < std::min(std::max(0, a - g), b)) and 
            (f < std::min(d, std::max(0, c - g))));
}
```

I am looking for the way of refactoring the expression to make it more readable.

Comment: That looks like it would take about 10 nanoseconds. Why do you think it needs optimization? If would only matter if you run it millions of times, if not billions. And then we need to know statistical properties of a..g to invent smarter solutions.

Comment: Optimizations should go to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thank you all, my mistake it should be just refactor/rewrite.

Comment: have you bothered to read the [tag:code-review] tag description?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optimization was the wrong term, but the code can be rewritten to find a better (more reduced, or succinct to the business) logic.

```
X < min(Y, Z)    <=>    X < Y and X < Z
X < max(Y, Z)    <=>    X < Y or X < Z            (less usefull)
```

Then possible rewrites are

```
return ((e < std::min(std::max(0, a - g), b)) and 
        (f < std::min(d, std::max(0, c - g))));

return ((e < std::max(0, a - g) and e < b)) and 
        (f < d and  f < std::max(0, c - g))));

return (e < 0 or e < a - g)
       and e < b
       and f < d
       and (f < 0 or f < c - g);
```

Depending on other constraints this might be reducable.

I would rather make a function `between` for the hard to read min+max.

```
return e < minmax(b, a - g, 0) and 
       f < minmax(d, c - g, 0);
```

I did not call this between, as maxmin is feasible too.

---

***Added***

@Jarod pointed me to the fact, that the OP mentioned all numbers would be **unsigned**. Then

```
max(a - g, 0)
```

probably should have been

```
a > g ? a - g : 0
```

Comment: As types are unsigned, `x < 0` is always `false`.

Comment: @Jarod that makes a - g and c - g creepy, I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

First of all, **leave such low level optimizations to your C++ compiler**. Probably a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `g++ -Wall -O2 -march=native` will [optimize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) better than you do. See Matt Goldbolt's CppCon2017 talk: [*What Has My Compiler Done for Me Lately? Unbolting the Compiler's Lid*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bSkpMdDe4g4).

If you believe (after profiling) that this particular piece of code should be optimized by hand, do so and document it. But you should profile first.

Be aware of the various approximate [timing](http://norvig.com/21-days.html#answers) of computations.

Remember that development time has its costs also. Most of the time they are more important than such low-level optimizations. Hence readability of the source code is also important (better naming of variables, extra temporary values, or additional comments could be important).