# Store lambdas/functions in std::vector without std::function

Tags: c++, vector, lambda

Bare in mind that I am trying to make the code as fast as I can, so suggestions that contain allocations or other slow code is not really an option.

I have a rendering system for a game I am building, and I am trying to store all the rendering process in a vector of functions, for example:

```
if(Monster.IsAlive)
{
    PushRender([...](){ // "..." means some stuff that I need to capture
        // Rendering the monster here...
    });
}
```

At the end of each loop, I go through all the rendering that I stored and I render them, after that I clear the array.

I want to be able to have a vector that contains multiple different functions AND to be able to access variables that are local or copied into the function (for example, lambda capture let me send variables to the functions without changing the signature of the function) or be able to store member-functions so I can access properties of the object.

Now, I tried several things to make this system work:

- I tried to store everything in `std::vector<std::function<void()>>`:

  **Problem**: `std::function` seem to allocate and deallocate memory every iteration of the loop, which is really critical to me, so `std::function` is not an option unless I can find a why to use it without performance hit.
- Tried using `std::vector<void(*Render)()>`:

  **Problem**: I can't use lambdas with this option, and I can't use member-function with these also (at least I couldn't). So only functions that are non-members which is a problem for me.

Thing I want from the system:

- Be fast, as fast as it can be.
- Be able to run multiple different functions without needing to use templates (I want a single `std::vector` that contain all the functions)

Anyone have idea how to implement such a system?

**If my explanation was not good enough here is an example:**

```
using Func = ...; // std::function<void()> for example

std::vector<Func> Functions;

while(Running)
{
    // clear all the rendering
    Functions.clear();

    if(Monster.IsAlive)
    {
        // 1. 
        Functions.push_back(Monster.Render); // Monster.Render = Function
        // Or 2.
        Functions.push_back(RenderMonster); // RenderMonster = Function
        // Or 3.
        Functions.push_back([] () {
            RenderImage(MonsterImage, X, Y);
            //....
        }); 
    }

    //... More code here

    // Render everything that is saved so far 
    for(Func func : Functions)
    {
        func();
    }
}
```

Comment: There are certain facts of life that are immutable. They are laws of nature. If you need to implement some kind of type erasure, the erased type information has to be stored somewhere. There's no such thing as free lunch. And as far as C++ goes, the only two options are automatic scope and dynamic scope. That's it. There are no other options. Unless you are prepared to capture the type-erased information in automatic scope and destroy it, at scope exit, your only option is dynamic scope (and memory allocation). No other options. Things don't work any other way. The End.

Comment: BTW, what compiler do you use? What optimization options? What operating system? What graphics toolkit?

Comment: Visual studio 2017 compiler, optimizations are disabled, Windows 10, OpenGL

Comment: I would recommend making your game [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) by publishing its source code (e.g. on [github](http://github.com/) or elsewhere) and trying to get some code review on it

Comment: @Zik332 "... optimizations are disabled ..." - why on earth would you *disable* the optimizer if you are trying to make things fast? That makes *no* sense.

Comment: @JesperJuhl It is not yet the release build and I want to make it easy to debug.

Comment: @Zik332 That's fine, but make sure to enable optimizations when you benchmark stuff or your results are going to be completely useless and meaningless.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Will do, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

> so suggestions that contain allocations or other slow code is not really an option.

This shows a misconception. Allocation is not necessarily slow. And code avoiding heap allocation is not always fast. And you could provide your own [allocators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator) (most standard [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) have an optional allocator template argument, e.g. the second template argument to [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)) if you believe you could make a faster one.

However, you could store smart pointers to lambdas, perhaps using `std::unique_ptr<std::function<void(void)>>`

You do need to manage the lifetime of these lambdas.

> Problem: `std::function` seem to allocate and deallocate memory every iteration of the loop, which is really critical to me,

Are you really sure of that? *Did you really benchmark?* In many cases, it would be fast enough for you (and the performance issues might be elsewhere).

I don't think that for game rendering, the bottleneck will be where you think today it is. **You need to [profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming))** your entire game. Of course, for benchmarking purposes, you need to enable [compiler optimizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler). See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47788641/841108) (and follow the links there).

A typical heap allocation (with `::operator new` or `malloc` ....) usually takes less than a microsecond (but sometimes much more). In most cases (but not all) that is not a performance issue.

> (I want a single std::vector that contain all the functions)

This is quite easy. Make a [tagged union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) type, perhaps using [`std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant), then have a `std::vector` of such types. Or, if you have a vector of pointers, make a common superclass (with some virtual functions) and have a vector of pointers to that class.

Comment: I overloaded new and delete and it seems that every iteration of the loop each `std::function` seem to use both

Comment: So what? It might be fast enough for your case.... My intuition is that what is taking time are the actual graphical primitives....

Comment: I didn't mean that the functions are the bottleneck, I just meant that allocating and deallocating every iteration could become a problem because I am pushing a lot of functions in the game, that could go up to about 100 or more, don't know if it is really that much of a problem but I figured trying to find a better solution

Comment: Yeah that could be, but another problem with my system is that I am hot-loading .DLL of the game every compilation, and I get exceptions if I try to do `clear()` on the array, and it come's from `std::function`, if I can manage to get rid of that I guess I will stay with that solution

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to mention that